# Has the IMU sensor to be located in the center of the wheels?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys
I'd like to ask you guys something about IMU position in my Robot which is differential drive type like PR2.
I put my IMU sensor on the center of the two wheels but I'm not sure I am doing right.
Has the IMU sensor to be located in the center of the two wheels? Or I can put it other space.
Please answer this question as soon as possible!
Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318885/has-the-imu-sensor-to-be-located-in-the-center-of-the-wheels?/) by [banseok Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/40528/banseok-kim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's nothing set in stone anywhere where you need to place any particular sensor. You can place it where ever you like. If you're trying to integrate some other stuff into your IMU (i.e. fuse orientation) then creating a IMU link in TF is probably necessary so another node can transform that data with respect to your base.

However you'd need to do that either way to set things up correctly so there's no additional overhead to placing your IMU in any given location. If you use an IMU that produces an orientation vector out, rigid body transformations tell you the orientation of a part is the orientation of the whole, so it actually doesn't matter at all where it is. If you're integrating angular velocities it may depending on the type of algorithm you're using.

tl;dr: no, you can put it anywhere. Just define the appropriate frame.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [banseok Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/40528/banseok-kim/) on 2019-03-20**:
Do you mean that I don't need to care about the difference from the location of my IMU sensor If I represent TF information of my IMU?
You mean TF2 package consider the acc value and gyro value? Am I right?